# SignalR Core - StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.1

I have two projects.

First, `WebApi` that contains Hub for using `SignalR`:

```
public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public async Task GetUpdateForServer(string call)
    {
        await this.Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReciveServerUpdate", call);
    }
}
```

I set up that Hub in `Startup.cs`:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ofc there is other stuff here

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes => routes.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/Notifications"));
    }
```

I belive that i would make notifications like this in `TaskController.cs`:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostTask([FromBody] TaskManager.Models.Task task)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }

        this.taskService.Add(task);

        //here, after POST i want to notify whole clients
        await this.notificationsHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("NewTask", "New Task in database!");

        return this.Ok(task);
    }
```

The problem starts here.

I have `WPF` app that contains `HubService`:

```
public class HubService
{
    public static HubService Instance { get; } = new HubService();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Notifications { get; set; }

    public async void Initialized()
    {
        this.Notifications = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var queryStrings = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { "group", "allUpdates" }
        };

        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("https://localhost:44365/Notifications", queryStrings);
        var hubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("NotificationsHub");

        hubProxy.On<string>("ReciveServerUpdate", call =>
        {
            //todo
        });

        await hubConnection.Start();
    }
}
```

And i initialize it in my `MainViewModel` constructor:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        HubService.Instance.Initialized();
    }
```

The problem starts in `await hubConnection.Start();`. From this line, i get an error:

> "StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcQWRtaW5cc291cmNlXHJlcG9zXFRhc2tNYW5hZ2VyXFRhc2tNYW5hZ2VyLXdlYmFwaVxOb3RpZmljYXRpb25zXHNpZ25hbHJcbmVnb3RpYXRl?=  Date: Tue, 28 May 2019 16:25:13 GMT  Server: Kestrel  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET  Content-Length: 0

My question is, what im doing wrong and how to connect to Hub in my `WebApi` project?

**EDIT**

Hub seems to work. I typed into my browser: `https://localhost:44365/notifications` and i got message:

> Connection ID required

**EDIT2**

`WPF` project is `.NET Framework 4.7.2` and `WebApi` is `Core 2.1`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

i found a solution.

Looking for it on the internet i discovered, that reference to `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` wont work with `SignalR` server based on Core.

I needed to change some things in my `WPF` project that is `.NET Framework 4.7.2`. First, delete reference to `AspNet.SignalR` and change it to `Core` one. To get this, just install this nugets in your `.Net Framework proj`:

[image]

Then, this service compiles without errors (idk if it works yet, but i get Connected count to 1 on my `WebApi` with `Core SignalR`):

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

public class HubService
{
    public static HubService Instance { get; } = new HubService();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Notifications { get; set; }

    public async void Initialized()
    {
        this.Notifications = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(UrlBuilder.BuildEndpoint("Notifications"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReciveServerUpdate", update =>
        {
            //todo, adding updates tolist for example
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

Now my `WPF` compiles without exception. Im getting notifications from server

Comment: Thank you for this. I created the simplest possible example of [WebApi Core to WPF](https://github.com/pwujczyk/ProductivityTools.Examples.SignalR.WebAPI2WPF "SignalR example").

Comment: @PawelWujczyk you can make it [even better :)](https://github.com/michasacuer/TaskManager). There you have WebApi with CQRS pattern as server and WPF as client

Comment: @michasaucer your example is not better. It's terribly complex and off the point. Pawel's demo is indeed the simplest possible example.