# SignalR Core, not getting response from server when client is connected

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-core, signalr, signalr.client

I am working on a SignalR Clinet-Server connection. My server is `WebApi Core 2.1` and my client is `WPF .NET Framework 4.7.2`.

On the client side I have a `singleton` hub service with one Instance to recive messages from server:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

public class HubService
{
    //singleton
    public static HubService Instance { get; } = new HubService();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Notifications { get; set; }

    public async void Initialize()
    {
        this.Notifications = new ObservableCollection<string>();

        var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(UrlBuilder.BuildEndpoint("Notifications"))
            .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReciveServerUpdate", update =>
        {
            //todo
        });

        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
}
```

i initialize it as singleton:

```
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        HubService.Instance.Initialize();
    }
```

While I'm debugging, on `MainWindowViewModel` im hitting that `HubService`.

On `Server` side its look like this.

`Hub`:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

public class NotificationsHub : Hub
{
    public async Task GetUpdateForServer(string call)
    {
        await this.Clients.Caller.SendAsync("ReciveServerUpdate", call);
    }
}
```

Im trigering send message in this way in my controller's methods:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostTask([FromBody] Task task)
    {
        if (!this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return this.BadRequest(this.ModelState);
        }

        this.taskService.Add(task);

        //here im calling sending message. When im debugging
        //i see one connection from my WPF with unique ConnectionId
        await this.notificationsHub.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReciveServerUpdate", "New Task in database!");

        return this.Ok(task);
    }
```

As I wrote before, while I'm debugging my `WebApi`, in `Clients` I have exactly one connection from my `WPF`. When I turn off `WPF`, `connection count = 0` so connections works perfectly.

But when I call `SendAsync()`, I'm not reciving any information in `WPF` in `hubConnection.On`. Funny thing, yesterday it works perfectly.

So, is my thinking about making `HubService` as static `singleton` is right? If its, why i cant recive messages from `WebApi` by `SignalR` when my `WPF` is connected to it?

I asked something similiar yesterday but i found a solution for it. Yesterday, my methods works, i could hit `hubConnection.On` when i get any message from `WebApi`. [My question from yestarday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56346533/signalr-core-statuscode-404-reasonphrase-not-found-version-1-1).

**EDIT**

Injection of `HUb` to controller:

```
    private readonly ITaskService taskService;

    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationsHub> notificationsHub;

    public TaskController(ITaskService taskService, IHubContext<NotificationsHub> notificationsHub)
    {
        this.taskService = taskService;
        this.notificationsHub = notificationsHub;
    }
```

And `Startup.cs` only `SignalR` things (i deleted other things not related to signal):

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes => routes.MapHub<NotificationsHub>("/Notifications"));
    }
```

**EDIT2**

Here is connection that i can get it, when my client `WPF` will register his connection:

[image]

Comment: Show the code how have you injected the `NotificationsHub` in your controller.

Comment: @TanvirArjel i added `Startup.cs` too (only with signalR). Look into my edit

Comment: What i know, when i have something like `static Instance` with `{ get; } = New` it should work like singleton, in this case i wanted to achive always-on `Hub` to recive messages from `Webapi` when someone call `Post` action

Comment: I tried your code with all kinds of clients (wpf/console/even with a browser),  it always works fine for me.The `hubConnection.On<string>("ReciveServerUpdate", update => {//todo});` always be invoked when I send a request to `PostTask`.  Is there a minimal demo that reproduces?

Comment: Beacuse... it works! I just didnt know that while im debugging i cant acces into `hub.On` method... So, i need to close this question or just leave it to te next generations? You are right @itminus. I just lost a lot of time trying to debug it

Comment: :)  That's really a question of Schrodinger .... I believe if you cannot reproduce the same issue, it's better to update your question to remind someone who wants to investigate. But don't remove this question in case that's a bug that we haven't realized for the present.

Comment: I belive, you can post an answer. I will mark it, because it helps tbh

Comment: Could you tell me, your instance of VS debugger get into `hubConnnection.On`? Becuase i pupulated `Notifications` with `updates` from that method, and debugger when i posted a task didnt trigger my breakpoint, but `Notifications` list was populated

Comment: @michasaucer Yes. The breakpoint is triggered both in VS & VSCode

Comment: @michasaucer When you say "didnt trigger my breakpoint", how do you configure the arguments of handler ? The number of arguments must be the same.

Comment: I just set up breakpoint in `hubConnection.On` and it never trigger. When i just cheking, what is in `Notifications`, there was messages from `Webapi` sent by hub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194159/discussion-between-itminus-and-michasaucer).

Comment: @michasaucer Have you restarted the client when you debug?

Comment: @itminus thanks for invest your time. Please, post answer so i will mark it as resolve for my problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried your code with all kinds of clients (wpf/console/even with a browser), it always works fine for me. The `hubConnection.On<string>("ReciveServerUpdate", update => {//todo});` always be invoked when I send a request to `PostTask`.

I'm not sure why (sometimes) it doesn't work for you somehow . However, when SignalR client has connected to server but gets no message from server, there're possible two reasons:

1. Your `PostTask([FromBody] Task task)` action method is not executed. Let's say this is an `ApiController` method, if the browser posts a request with a `Content-Type` of `application/www-x-form-urlencoded` by accident, the invocation of `Clients.All.SendAsync(..., ...);` won't be executed at all.
2. The handler of SigalR client (`hubConnection.On<>(method,handler)`) must has exactly the same argument list as the invocation in order to receive messages. We must be very careful when dealing with this.
3. Finally, it's better to add a reference to [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console)

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console" Version="2.2.*" />
   ```

   so that we could enable logging to troubleshoot :

   ```
   var hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
       .WithUrl(UrlBuilder.BuildEndpoint("Notifications"))
       .ConfigureLogging(logging =>{
           logging.AddConsole();        // enable logging
       })
       .Build();
   ```

Comment: Please, mention that my code works in your answer for the next generation of .NET developers (some of them diving straight into answers)